# Can pwrite in C be used to write file in parallel?

Tags: c, multithreading, file, io

I am wondering when we are going to use pwrite to write a data to different locations with multiple threads.
(I.e., Each thread writes a data to the single file but in different offset.)

Here is the sample code.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

char buf[50000000];

void *p_function(void * arg)
{
        int s,e;
        s = clock();
        int* arr = (int*)arg;
        int ret = pwrite(arr[0], buf, sizeof(buf), 100000000*arr[1]);
        e = clock();
        printf("Elapsed time : %d\n", e-s);
}

int main(void)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {
                buf[i] = 5;
        }

        pthread_t pthread[3];
        int thr_id;
        int status;

        int fd = open("File", O_RDWR);

        int arg[3][2];

        int thread_num = 3;

        int s,e;
        s = clock();
        for(int i = 0; i < thread_num; i++) {
                arg[i][1] = i;
                arg[i][0] = fd;
            pthread_create(&pthread[i], NULL, p_function, (void*)arg[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < thread_num; i++) {
                pthread_join(pthread[i], (void **)&status);
        }
        e = clock();
        printf("Elapsed time : %d", e-s);

        return 0;
}
```

```
File
 ------------------------------------------------
|   Location 1   |   Location 2  |   Location 3  |
 ------------------------------------------------
     ㄴthread 1        ㄴthread 2      ㄴthread 3
```

With this code, I see there is no benefit of multithreading.
(I expected that elapsed time is much faster than that of single thread, which is writing 150000000 bytes with one thread.)

Do I miss something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I/O is almost always a major bottleneck in programs. Especially if you happen to read from or write to an old-style hard-drive and not an SSD.

Comment: https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/09/single-writer-principle.html might be an interesting read.

Comment: Why do you expect that writing the same file through multiple threads will be faster than using one single thread? On a non SSD drive, I would expect the opposite, because the disk hardware is optimized for sequential accesses. And even on a SSD drive I would make no assumption without testing...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am using NVMe SSD and I heard that it is good for parallel processing.

Comment: @H.Potter It's not that hard to saturate the I/O pipeline of most systems, especially if you don't know the details of your system.  All the disk speed in the world on an NVMe disk in a PCIe x16 slot won't help if your motherboard manufacturer saved some money or motherboard real estate by only using a 4-lane PCIe bus. When buying systems, almost no one looks at things like bus speed and latency, or memory latency.  They look at how much/how fast the RAM is, and the CPUs, and maybe how big the PCIe connectors are.  Guess one area where motherboard manufacturers pinch pennies...

Comment: (I'm looking at you, HP...)

Comment: Reading a big chunk of data is not optimal as it will likely not fit in the CPU cache. Moreover, OS do not always use a zero-copy implementation of such IO operations. Thus, it may cause the buffer to be copied multiple time in RAM which is not efficient on fast NVME SSD for example (negligible for HDD). Some OS can use a lock so that parallel IO operation are serialized (in the worst case, even a [giant lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_lock). Alternatively, the driver can serialize the operation or the device regarding the access pattern and the device itself.